# i tried to install virtual box un ubuntu and now i cant do many things from my terminal

Tags: 14.04

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ focal: /usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ focal: /usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: You have tagged 14.04, that version has been EOL for ages, What Ubuntu version are you really using ? I can see focal mentioned in the errors above, that is 20.04.